# IE issue when a GIF image is shown while navigating from one page to another

Tags: internet-explorer, settimeout, gif

I have a master page which has a code contatining a `div` tag with the image and some text should be displayed. There are six pages in my project. Under each page when I press `Save` and `continue` button which navigates to other page.

It does lot of processing, so for the delay a GIF image shows processing with some animation on it.

**The animation works correctly when a user clicks on the `save` and `continue` button, but it gets stopped when the processing is done in the current page and starting to load the new page.**

I had tried many ways by using `SetTimeout` methods. But cannot solve this issue. Can you please resolve the issue for me?

Comment: *I see this is a very old post, anyways...* So I take it you are using AJAX and on getting the response from the server the Javascript will change the window location to the next page that needs to be loaded?